# How to use Dojo with Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dojo

I am trying to get a simple dojo module to work with angular2.
However, I am not able to load both the angular2 libraries and the dojo libraries. 
I have tried to load dojo first then angular and vice versa to no avail. Here is what I have tried:

main.ts

```
/// <reference path="typings/dojo/dojo.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts"/>

import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

declare var require: (moduleId: string) => any;
import dom = require("dojo/dom");
import fx = require("dojo/fx")



@Component({
    selector: 'greeting'
})
@View({
    template: `<div id="innergreeting">Hello From Angular and</div>`
})
class DojoTest{
    constructor(){
        var greeting = dom.byId("innergreeting");
        greeting.innerHTML += ' Dojo!';
        fx.slideTo({
            node: greeting,
            top: 100,
            left: 200
        }).play();
    }
}
bootstrap(DojoTest);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>

    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <greeting></greeting>
    <script>System.import('main');</script>

</body>

</html>
```

ERROR:

GET http://localhost:8080/dojo/dom.js 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:8080/dojo/fx.js 404 (Not Found)

I am fairly new to AngularJs so all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> GET http://localhost:8080/dojo/dom.js 404 (Not Found)
>   GET http://localhost:8080/dojo/fx.js 404 (Not Found)

This is triggered by the following code:

```
import dom = require("dojo/dom");
import fx = require("dojo/fx");
```

*Make sure you have `dojo` installed*

Comment: What else should i include other than:


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>


and 

/// <reference path="typings/dojo/dojo.d.ts"/> ?

Comment: `jspm install dojo` and remove the `script` tag

Comment: I imagine it should also be possible to configure the SystemJS loader to load modules from the Dojo package from the CDN if desired.  With AMD loaders one would typically use `packages` or `paths`, but it looks like maybe [`map`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#map) is a better fit in SystemJS.